# How do I find the missing income value using knn in R

Tags: r, dataset, knn

Here is the dataset I created:

```
ID <- c(NA,1,2,3)
Age <- c(30,25,33,35)
Asset_Size <- c(60,50,60,80)
Income <- c(NA,100000,90000,150000)
chart1 <- data.frame(ID,Age,Asset_Size,Income)
```

I'm trying to find the missing value of income for customer x if K = 1 and method = “un-weighted vote".
So I'm trying to find the correct knn code. Here is what I've been trying so far.

```
knn(chart1,k = 1, prob=TRUE)
```

It's looking for test, train, and cl. Not sure where to go from there. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original data frame looks like this:

```
chart1
#   ID Age Asset_Size Income
# 1 NA  30         60     NA
# 2  1  25         50 100000
# 3  2  33         60  90000
# 4  3  35         80 150000
```

So you are looking for a prediction of income for customer `X`, with the information of `Age` and `Asset_Size`, with `knn`, it just means to find out which of the known customer `1,2,3` `X` is closest to.

So the training data set would be the `Age` and `Asset_Size` for customers `1,2,3`:

```
train <- chart1[2:4, 2:3]
```

And testing data set would be the `Age` and `Asset_Size` for customer `X`:

```
test <- chart1[1, 2:3]
```

The cluster would be just the `ID` since you are doing one nearest neighbor:

```
cl <- chart1[2:4, 1]
```

Pass these data set to `knn` as specified by docs, you get:

```
knn(train, test, cl, k = 1, prob = T)
[1] 2
attr(,"prob")
[1] 1
Levels: 1 2 3
```

So `X` is closest to customer 2 and the predicted income should be `90000`, which makes sense if you look at their `Age` and `Asset_size` information since they are the closest.

Comment: Hey if you have a free momment could you take a look at my other question? Thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38253784/how-to-find-the-missing-value-using-kknn-not-knn-in-r?noredirect=1#comment63928811_38253784